# Using 3D trigonometry to find an angle

Tags: trigonometry

I have the question "Calculate the angle between the line DF and the plane ABCD in the cuboid pictured below, giving your answer to 1 decimal place."

[image]

I know how to pretty much solve this. I just don't understand which angle the question is referring too.

Is it referring to the angle labelled B ?

Comment: No, minimum angle between $BD,FD$ what is cos $BDF$?

Comment: Look at the triangle $BDF$ ... do a bit of Pythagorus to get the distances & then do some trig to get the angle at $B$.

Comment: Picture the triangle DBF, which is a right angled-triangle. The angle being referred to is the angle at D in this triangle

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I have solved the question now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I see you have solved this in comments since I started typing, but I'll leave this here as an answer anyway)...*

---

The angle you need is $\angle BDF$. The reason that is the correct angle is because $B$ is the nearest point on the plane to $F$, since the normal to the plane at $B$ goes through $F$.

You can use the Pythagorean theorem to get the value of $DB$, then take the arctangent for your result.